# Qt, OPENCV APPLICATION DEPLOYEMENT ON RASPBERRY PI

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

hamzaelazizi 2 minutes ago

Hello everyone, i'm currently trying to link my OpenCV library with my Qt creator, in order to make a cross-compiled application, that will allow me to open a picture stored on my Raspi and display it on my Raspi.
So, the application is built on my Ubuntu host machine and then compiled on my Raspi.
I've already established a toolchain for cross-compilation and it's working as it should, but whenever i try to to deploy this OpenCV test application i get this error when building : "*/usr/local/lib/libopencv_gapi.so:-1: error: file not recognized: file format not recognized*"

Here's my .pro code :

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt


INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv4

LIBS += `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`


SOURCES += \
    main.cpp
```

Comment: Did you rebuild openCV with your cross toolchain?

Comment: Does this help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/116592/install-opencv-in-a-raspberry-pi-3-with-c ?

Comment: @markus-nm No, actually i did not do that, once i had installed the toolchain and got everything working i did not go near it because it has cost me already too much time to set it up so i didn't want it all to go to waste

Comment: A piece of software is indifferent to your feelings. If you dont build openCV for your target platform, you cannot build an application that links to it.